# Zend Framework 2 and PHP 7

Tags: zend-framework2, php-7

I noticed how to use PHP 7 features you have to use `declare(strict_types=1)` on every file (or that's what I read on php.net). Now, I'm using Zend Framework 2 and want to use PHP 7's features, do I have to put `declare(strict_types=1)` in every php file or is there a way to have it load it once and not put it in every php file I make.

Or better yet, not have to put it in at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have to refactor every class anyway it makes sense to put it in every file you want to work with strict types. Classes you don 't want to work with strict types don 't need the declare statement.

As far as I know you have to add it in every file (which should work with strict types). There is no way to load it globally.

Comment: so I would only have to use it in the php files that actually use php 7 features and not every single one?

Comment: For example, I only use php7 type declarations and return type in my models, so I would only need to use declare there and not anywhere else?

Comment: Absolutely right. Just use the declare statement in your models, if you won 't use it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, just what I wanted to know